# Accessing scene item list without crashing QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5, mapcanvas

Temporary graphics items can be added to the canvas, e.g with.

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
point = QgsPointXY(10, 55)
vm = QgsVertexMarker(canvas)
vm.setCenter(point)
```

and can be removed by using `iface.mapCanvas().scene()`:

```
scene = canvas.scene()
scene.removeItem(vm)
```

My **first question** is: How to manage cases where there are such items already added to the canvas when the code starts, and no item reference is available to delete them using the method above?

My **second question** is actually related to the way I tried to answer the first question: In my case, (QGIS 3.14) `canvas.scene()` is an instance of `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene` for which the method [items()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#items) is supposed to get a list of existing items. However:

```
items = scene.items()
```

just crashes QGIS. What is the problem?